# check multi access in YII with execute just single query db

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii framework, and CDbAuthManager class for authorization users.
For check one access can use this code:

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('post');
```

This code execute a db query, It's here in background:

```
SELECT * FROM `auth_item` WHERE name='post'
```

Now If I check other access, then execute another db query:

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('comment');
SELECT * FROM `auth_item` WHERE name='comment'
```

Now if I need to check many of access, so execute many db query.
Now, how can I check multi access, So that just execute single query db.
For example I wish have a code be like this:

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess(array('post', 'comment'));
```

And maybe execute be like this query for that:

```
SELECT * FROM `auth_item` WHERE name IN ('post', 'comment');
```

Any idea?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution and write a component for it here: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth-component/

Answer (score 0):

i think the following code, may work for you

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('name', array('post', 'comment'))
```

Comment: It's wrong, the second argument is for set params for bizRule, and is not for check an operation rule.